# Scrapy playwright does not send the next request via scrapy

Tags: scrapy, playwright

I have below example

```python
import json

import scrapy
import scrapy_playwright
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy_playwright.handler import Page, PageMethod


class GreetingsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "greetings"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]

    custom_settings = {
        "LOG_LEVEL": "INFO",
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        url = "https://www.example.com"
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url,
            callback=self.parse,
            meta={"playwright": True, "playwright_include_page": True},
        )


    async def parse(self, response):
        print("Hello ")
        page: Page = response.meta["playwright_page"]
        await page.close()
        print("Hello from parse next")
        yield scrapy.Request(
            response.url,
            callback=self.parse_next,
            meta={"playwright": True},
            errback=self.errback_close_page,
        )
        print("Hello from second parse next")
        

    def parse_next(self, response):
        print(response.url)
```

The problem here is parse_next never gets called.

This is output i get

```
Hello 
Hello from parse next
Hello from second parse next
2022-11-03 07:26:03 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2022-11-03 07:26:03 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 193,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 260537,
...
}
2022-11-03 07:26:03 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
2022-11-03 07:26:03 [scrapy-playwright] INFO: Closing download handler
2022-11-03 07:26:03 [scrapy-playwright] INFO: Closing download handler
2022-11-03 07:26:03 [scrapy-playwright] INFO: Closing browser
```

The problem is parse_next never gets called and as a result the line
print(response.url) never gets executed.

Any ideas on this please.

I have followed the playwright and scrapy documentation but I am not sure what am i missing here.

This is a toy example and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Would you share the webpage?

Comment: Fazlul my apologies I cannot share the actual web page.That was indeed very polite of you asking me without getting annoyed.

Comment: Or share any real url  as an example that's about to your webpage

Comment: Sure let me work out a real example.

Answer (score 1):

1. "playwright_include_page method is obsolute, use `playwright_page_methods` instead
2. Select the desired data element from the webpage and use as a page method
3. The webpage I used here as an example which contains 4 tables list but my aim was to select the first one which is the page method selection and I wanted to scrape data inside it which element selections are in def `parse(self,response):`

**Example:**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_playwright.page import PageMethod

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test"
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(

            url="https://info.uniswap.org/#/",
            callback=self.parse,
            meta={
                "playwright": True,
                "playwright_page_methods": [
                    PageMethod("wait_for_selector", '((//*[@class="sc-brqgnP klmLHi"])[1]//*[@class="sc-brqgnP klmLHi"])[1]'),
                ],
            },
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        
        products = response.xpath('((//*[@class="sc-brqgnP klmLHi"])[1]//*[@class="sc-brqgnP klmLHi"])[1]//div[@class="sc-bXGyLb ePvtyo"]')
        for product in products:
            yield {
            'price':product.xpath('.//*[@class="sc-chPdSV goKJOd sc-bMVAic eOIWzG css-63v6lo"][1]/text()').get(),
          
            }
```

**Output:**

```
{'price': '$1.00'}
2022-11-03 14:27:14 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://info.uniswap.org/#/>
{'price': '$1.55k'}
2022-11-03 14:27:14 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://info.uniswap.org/#/>
{'price': '$1.00'}
2022-11-03 14:27:14 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://info.uniswap.org/#/>
{'price': '$20.28k'}
2022-11-03 14:27:14 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://info.uniswap.org/#/>
{'price': '$1.00'}
2022-11-03 14:27:14 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://info.uniswap.org/#/>
{'price': '$1.00'}
2022-11-03 14:27:14 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://info.uniswap.org/#/>
{'price': '$1.21'}
2022-11-03 14:27:14 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://info.uniswap.org/#/>
{'price': '$1.53k'}
2022-11-03 14:27:14 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://info.uniswap.org/#/>
{'price': '$0.60'}
2022-11-03 14:27:14 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://info.uniswap.org/#/>
{'price': '$1.00'}
```

**settings.pt file:** You have to add the following requirements in your settings.py file

```
DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS = {
    "http": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
    "https": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
}

TWISTED_REACTOR = "twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor"


PLAYWRIGHT_DEFAULT_NAVIGATION_TIMEOUT = 10000
```

Answer (score 1):

-try turning off Headless browser settings to see if you're actually loading the site
-if you are and if its just stuck,add this to your request: dont_filter=True